# Perl: concatenate variable inside variable?

Tags: perl, concatenation

Inside variable I would like to concatenate other variable:

```
my %hash = (
 DNS_AD_toto => ['10.0.0.1'],
 DNS_OP_toto => ['192.168.0.2', '10.0.0.2'],
 DNS_ZA_toto => ['192.168.0.3'],
);

foreach my $abc ("AD", "OP"){
  print $DNS_${abc}_toto[0];
}
```

But `print $DNS_$a_toto[0]` doesn't work because `$DNS_` doesn't exist.
So, how to concatenate two variables in only one line?

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're asking here - please can you take a moment to review and refine your question? Please see [ask] for what makes a good question. Code is a good start, but we can't tell what your desired results are.

Comment: I will point out though - you're assigning an anonymous hash `{}` to an array. `@DNS_AD_toto` - which doesn't work very well. Likewise - your `eq` is using an unquoted string, which'll be a _version number_ not what you're intending. And your foreach loop - you're not including the array names. Please turn on `strict;` and `warnings;` because that'll help you write some code that works.

Comment: There is also `$a`, which is a reserved variable name that is used in `sort` blocks/subs alongside `$b`. Chose meaningful variable names instead.

Comment: What output are you hoping to get based on this?

Comment: I find the question very clear ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't answer your question, because it's not clear what your question is. I'll point out though - there are several problems with your code which means it probably isn't going to work - fix these first:

- Turn on `use strict;` and `use warnings;`. Fix any errors generated - these should be the first two lines of everything you write.
- `my @DNS_AD_toto = {'10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2'};` probably isn't doing what you think it's doing.

`{}` denote anonymous hashes. So what you're creating here is an anonymous hash, and then inserting it into an array. Your array is one element long, and contains a key-value pair. That's almost certainly not what you wanted.

e.g.:

```
$VAR1 = [
          {
            '10.0.0.1' => '10.0.0.2'
          }
        ];
```

- As mentioned in the comments - don't use `$a` - it's a reserved variable for `sort`. In fact - don't use any single letter variable names. There's rarely a good reason for it.
- You're talking about symbolic references - those are nasty. Don't. Use a hash instead.  See here for more detail: http://perl.plover.com/varvarname.html

What you *probably* want is:

```
my %DNS_toto = (
   'AD' => [ '10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2' ],
   'OP' => [ '192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2' ],
);
print Dumper \%DNS_toto;
```

Which gives:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'AD' => [
                    '10.0.0.1',
                    '10.0.0.2'
                  ],
          'OP' => [
                    '192.168.0.1',
                    '192.168.0.2'
                  ]
        };
```

(But I'm still not quite clear what your desired end result it - update your question and I'll update this answer).

Edit: Following question update:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
    DNS_AD_toto => ['10.0.0.1'],
    DNS_OP_toto => [ '192.168.0.2', '10.0.0.2' ],
    DNS_ZA_toto => ['192.168.0.3'],
);

foreach my $abc ( "AD", "OP" ) {
    print $hash{ "DNS_" . $abc . "_toto" }[0], "\n";
}
```

Alternatively:

```
foreach my $key ( "DNS_AD_toto", "DNS_OP_toto" ) {
    print $hash{$key},"\n";
}
```

Or:

```
foreach my $abc ( grep {m/(AD|OP)/} keys %hash ) {
    print $hash{$abc}[0], "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) thx

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to generate code.

```
my %DNS_toto = (
    AD => [ '10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2' ],
    OP => [ '192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2' ],
);

for my $foo (qw( AD OP )) {
   if ($DNS_toto{$foo}[0] eq '192.168.0.2') {
      ...
   }

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a hash when you want to manipulate variable names,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
  DNS_AD_toto => ['10.0.0.1', '10.0.0.2'],
  DNS_OP_toto => ['192.168.0.1', '192.168.0.2'],
);

foreach my $s ("AD", "OP") {
  my $key = "DNS_${s}_toto";

  if( $hash{$key}[0] eq "192.168.0.2") {
    print 'It is AD'
  } 
  if( $hash{$key}[0] eq "10.0.0.2") {
    print 'It is OP'
  }

}
```